# PHP look at past and predict the next number

Tags: php, numbers

ok, so I have a list of numbers

1,5,8,0,4,3

what I would like to do is for a PHP script to look at the numbers and get the average. if that average is lower then the last number then + the last number by the 1/2 of the average

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if u r asking for something like this--

```
<?php

$a = array(1,5,8,0,4,3);

$b = array_sum($a);

if($b < end($a))
{
$c = end($a)+ ($b/2);
echo $c;
}
```

Comment: `1/2($b)` may be valid algebra, but it is not PHP and likely not what you intended. Perhaps `$b / 2`?

Answer (score 2):

Sum the array using `array_sum`. Divide that by the length of the array, obtained using `count`. You now have the average, and I'm sure you can figure out the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 
`

```
$avg = array_sum($numlis);
$lastelem = end($numlis);
if(lastelem == FALSE){
  echo "empty array";
  exit(1);
}
elseif($avg < $lastelem) {
  $val = $lastelem + (.5*$avg);
  echo $val;
}
else {
  echo "avg is greater";
}`
```

I included some error checking